# d3.js - Steady links between nodes on force diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I modified a force diagram to change node circles into images, but would like some consistency with the way links are connected, like how a flowchart is. Similar to what is seen on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnyc/uxdozyvu/).

There may be something that needs to be modified in this code:

```
var forceLayout = d3.layout.force()
.nodes(nodes)
.links([])
.gravity(gravity)
.size([width, height])
    .charge(function(d){
        var charge = -500;
        if (d.index === 0) charge = 10 * charge;
        return charge;
    });
```

The way that fiddle has it, the `charge`and the `linkDistance` makes it look consistent, but changing the values to what's here doesn't help.

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-200)
        .linkDistance(50)
        .size([width + margin.left + margin.right, height + margin.top + margin.bottom]);
```

Here's a link to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jenrocodes/mbynon42/).

Comment: If you have a specific layout in mind, the force layout isn't suitable. [cola.js](http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/) may provide what you need.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks. Will cola.js be able to display tooltips on hover as well? The chart I'm building is quite data-driven so D3 may be more suitable..

Comment: It doesn't replace D3, it extends it.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle code, I set in the CSS part row 7 to `width: 600px;` instead of `width: 80%;`.
Also I added in the JavaScript, in row 118 a global variable

```
var width = 600
    height = 800
```

and I made the `.linkDistance(30)`

Hope this helps you..

Comment: Thanks Sara! in row 118 what global variable did you add?

Comment: var width = 600
      height = 800

Comment: well you can take whatever you like as height and width. Just like it fits your layout. It just works better if you put a variable like this directly in the JavaScript..